# Assertion in C with negative float

Tags: c

I wrote a simple function and would like to get know the assert macro in use. When I test the function (moving_hysteresis) after the sixth assert function I get an abort and I could not find out why. The moving_hysteresis() function follows:

```
float moving_hysteresis(float Delta,float temp)
{    
float delta=Delta;
float temp_min=ZERO;
float temp_max=delta;
float result;

if(temp<=temp_max)
    {
        if(temp>=temp_min)
            {
                result=temp;
                return result;
            }
        else
            {
                result=temp+delta;
                return result;
            }
    }
else
    {
        result=temp-delta;
        return  result;
    }
 }
```

If I try to test this with

```
 assert(moving_hsysteresis(5.00,-5.01)==(float)-0.01);
```

I get an assertion and I could not find out why... 
For example, if I try to test this with

```
assert(moving_hsysteresis(5.00,-2.36)==(float)2.64);
```

it works correctly. Somebody have any idea?

Comment: Testing for exact floating-point values is almost ALWAYS a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you all of your help and comment! It is clear now for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first assertion works because the difference is just too small for the precision to work (Floating point precision is limited).

That's why your second assertion works.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float a=5.00;
    float b=5.01;
    float c=0.01;
    printf("%.25f",a-b+c);
}
```

The value should be mathematically zero, but floating-point errors mean that the result will not be precisely zero. On my system this prints out `-0.0000002291053533554077148`.

For this reason, testing floats for inequality typically checks to within a small elipson instead of testing for exact inequality.